# How to add an image to my facebook app

Tags: facebook

I've created an application in the developers section (https://developers.facebook.com/). I needed an application key so I could connect a third party commenting service to my blog. The question is, how do I change the applications logo? Replace the default "atom" logo so that when the popup opens asking for permission to use their facebook details, I have my websites logo instead of that atom.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'App details' tab in the developer section. There is a section there for updating the artwork. See screenshot below.

[image: Facebook Settings screenshot]

This page can be found at

https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/[YOUR-APP-ID]/app-details/

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark, as per...

http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png